# Filter a pandas dataframe conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter a dataframe, and I can't figure out how to filter to the values I actually want. I don't really know how to explain what I'm trying to do (which makes searching a real pain), so a sample snippet is below:

```
race    driver     team      ...
1       Alonso     Ferrari
1       Massa      Ferrari
1       Hamilton   McLaren
...
2       Alonso     McLaren
2       Hamilton   McLaren
2       Massa      Ferrari
...
```

What I want is to be able to filter based on Alonso's team for the specific race, in order to find his teammate - such that for race 1, I get Alonso and Massa, but for race 2 I get Alonso and Hamilton. So the intended result after filtering is:

```
race    driver     team      ...
1       Alonso     Ferrari
1       Massa      Ferrari
2       Alonso     McLaren
2       Hamilton   McLaren
...
```

I've been able to filter to just Alonso's rows with `df[df.driver == "Alonso"]`, or to all Ferrari and McLaren rows (there are more teams than just those two in the data) with `df.team.isin(teams)` where `teams` lists all teams listed in rows where driver matches Alonso, but I can't seem to combine the two filters in a way that filters conditionally based on which team matches Alonso that race.

<sub>This is a personal project that I'm using to sharpen back up on Python, which I've mostly self-taught, so apologies if there's an obvious solution that I've missed.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

Use groupby + filter:

```
df.groupby(['race', 'team']).filter(lambda x: x['driver'].eq('Alonso').sum() > 0)
```

Output:

```
race    driver        team
0    1    Alonso        Ferrari
1    1    Massa        Ferrari
3    2    Alonso        McLaren
4    2    Hamilton    McLaren
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'race': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
         'driver': ['Alonso', 'Massa', 'Hamilton', 'Alonso', 'Hamilton', 'Massa'],
         'team': ['Ferrari', 'Ferrari', 'McLaren', 'McLaren', 'McLaren', 'Ferrari']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

df
```

Output:

```
race    driver        team
0    1    Alonso        Ferrari
1    1    Massa        Ferrari
2    1    Hamilton    McLaren
3    2    Alonso        McLaren
4    2    Hamilton    McLaren
5    2    Massa        Ferrari
```

Comment: `filter` can be slow, a more efficient approach would be `out = df[df['driver'].eq('Alonso').groupby([df['race'], df['team']]).transform('any')]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to get the teams for every race. If that's the case, one option that helps is to `groupby` the columns you want. For instance,

```
for group, frame in df.groupby(["race", "team"]):
    print(frame, "\n")
```

will split the dataframe into groups of drivers that share race and team:

```
   race  driver     team
0     1  Alonso  Ferrari
1     1   Massa  Ferrari

   race    driver     team
2     1  Hamilton  McLaren

   race driver     team
5     2  Massa  Ferrari

   race    driver     team
3     2    Alonso  McLaren
4     2  Hamilton  McLaren
```

With a grouper like the one returned by `groupby`, you can `agg`regate data across groups in order to obtain new tables. For instance,

```
races = df.groupby(["race", "team"]).agg(lambda x: x)
print(races)
```

gives the list of teams with members per each race:

```
                          driver
race team
1    Ferrari     [Alonso, Massa]
     McLaren            Hamilton
2    Ferrari               Massa
     McLaren  [Alonso, Hamilton]
```

Other options for aggregating can be obtained by specifying your own aggregation function as per [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea using foor loops.
First, create a loop to seach over each race (ex: 1,2,3,...), then look for the team of Alonso in that race (Ferrari, McLaren...), and then create a data frame where only use the elements for the race and the team. Here is the example:
For the dataframe:

| race | driver | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alonso | Ferrari |
| 1 | Massa | Ferrari |
| 1 | ab | mc |
| 1 | Hamilton | mc |
| 2 | Alonso | mc |
| 2 | Massa | mc |
| 2 | ab | Ferrari |
| 2 | Hamilton | Ferrari |

```
#create a new dataframe to store the results
final_df=pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1,df['race'].max()+1):   #for loop to search in each race who is the teammate of alonso
    #search for each race i and search for the driver alonso
    df_per_race=df[df.race == i]
    #get the team of the driver alonso
    team=df_per_race[df_per_race.driver == 'alonso'].team.iloc[0]

    #search for each race, the teammate of the driver alonso
    new_df = df[(df.race == i) & (df.team == team)]

    #concatenate the dataframes
    final_df=pd.concat([final_df,new_df])


print(final_df)
```

and you will get something like this:

| index | race | driver | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | alonso | ferrari |
| 1 | 1 | massa | ferrari |
| 6 | 2 | massa | mc |
| 7 | 2 | alonso | mc |

Answer (score -1):

why don't you just filter out those races Alonso not included? filter out races without Alonso, then sort by teamnames

Comment: Because Alonso has been on many teams, and if I'm understanding the suggestion correctly, that would leave all Ferrari and McLaren (and several others that aren't in the snippet) rows in the data. I don't want Hamilton included in the first race nor do I want Massa included in the second, and if I filter simply by team names, both of those will be included in the data.

Comment: oh i get it. guess i misunderstood your intention

Comment: Note to reviewers: [Answers which misunderstand the question are not Very Low Quality.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272925/are-answers-which-misunderstood-the-question-low-quality) This should be reviewed "Looks OK". (If you think that the answer is unhelpful, that's what voting is for).